# Facebook: Get User Access Token using Facebook.Json

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have some C# code that retrieves an access token using Facebook.JsonObject and can post to my profile wall on facebook with no problems.

However, if I try to use that same access token to retrieve details of my facebook business pages so I can post to them, then I get the message "user access token is required to request this resource".

I thought the access token I had retrieved that allowed me to post to my profile was a user access token.  What is the difference, and how do I get a user access token?

This is the code I am using to get the access token:

```
facebook.JsonObject AuthResult = (Facebook.JsonObject)Oauth.GetApplicationAccessToken(parameters);

object Access_Token = "";
AuthResult.TryGetValue("access_token", out Access_Token);
FacebookClient FBClient = new FacebookClient(Access_Token.ToString());
```

More information:

I need my customer's c# application to post directly to my customer's facebook business page via code without the application "allow access" box popping up and any redirects to applicatoins taking place. Therefore I need to get the User Access Token programatically without facebook being logged in or open etc.

Any (non-sarcastic) help very gratefully received.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I thought the access token I had retrieved that allowed me to post to my profile was a user access token.

Does that method name,

```
(Facebook.JsonObject)Oauth.GetApplicationAccessToken(parameters);
                              ===========
```

*really* sound to you as if it was supposed to give back a *user* access token? Sorry, but to me it doesn’t …

If you are not familiar with the different types of authentication and access tokens, please read this first: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: thanks for your charming response, however that's not quite what i'm looking for.  I need my customer's c# application to post directly to my customer's facebook business page via code without the application "allow access" box popping up and any redirects to applicatoins taking place.  Therefore I need to get the User Access Token programatically without facebook being logged in or open etc.

Comment: You seem to want a page access token, and how to get one of those … is described in the docs.

Comment: To get a page access token, you first need a user access token - i was getting the message "you need a user access token to request this resource".  I have used the get access token tool on the facebook developer page, and added that into my code for testing purposes, and using this access token I can post to my customer's page.  However, that access token has a 2 hour expiry, so I need to programatically generate one and this is where I am stuck.  All the documentation/forum posts etc I have read either relate to posting to a profile (which I can do), or a "proper" facebook app.

Comment: _“However, that access token has a 2 hour expiry”_ – https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/